# Search bar disappears on small screen bootstrap css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I bought a react template online I couldn't figure it out why this form search bar is hidden on small screen size.

```
 <div className="col-lg-8 col-xxl-4-5col d-none d-lg-block">
 <div className="header-search header-search-extended header-search-visible header-search-no-radius d-none d-lg-block">
```

I tried changing "d-none d-lg-block" to "d-block" but still did not work

I am not a css expert so I need a work around to make it work .

here is the full div html code:

I need form to be displayed on all screen size

```
<div className="header-middle">
        <div className={container}>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-auto col-lg-3 col-xl-3 col-xxl-2">
              <button className="mobile-menu-toggler">
                <span className="sr-only">Toggle mobile menu</span>
                <i className="icon-bars"></i>
              </button>
              <Link to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} className="logo">
                <img
                  src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/logo.png`}
                  alt="Molla Logo"
                  width="105"
                  height="25"
                />
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="col col-lg-9 col-xl-9 col-xxl-10 header-middle-right">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-8 col-xxl-4-5col d-none d-lg-block">
                  <div className="header-search header-search-extended header-search-visible header-search-no-radius d-none d-lg-block">
                    <Link to="#" className="search-toggle" role="button">
                      <i className="icon-search"></i>
                    </Link>

                    <form method="get" onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
                      <div className="header-search-wrapper search-wrapper-wide">
                        <div className="select-custom">
                          <select id="cat" name="cat">
                            <option value="">All Departments</option>
                            <option value="1">Fashion</option>
                            <option value="2">- Women</option>
                            <option value="3">- Men</option>
                            <option value="4">- Jewellery</option>
                            <option value="5">- Kids Fashion</option>
                            <option value="6">Electronics</option>
                            <option value="7">- Smart TVs</option>
                            <option value="8">- Cameras</option>
                            <option value="9">- Games</option>
                            <option value="10">Home &amp; Garden</option>
                            <option value="11">Motors</option>
                            <option value="12">- Cars and Trucks</option>
                            <option value="15">- Boats</option>
                            <option value="16">
                              - Auto Tools &amp; Supplies
                            </option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <label htmlFor="q" className="sr-only">
                          Search
                        </label>
                        <input
                          onChange={inputChangeHandler}
                          type="search"
                          className="form-control"
                          name="q"
                          id="q"
                          placeholder="Search product ..."
                          value={search}
                          required
                        />
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                          <i className="icon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                        <input
                         style={{display:"none"}}
                          type="file"
                          name="file"
                          onChange={onChangeHandler}
                          ref={imageInput}
                        />
                         <div className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={somethingtohappen}>
                          <i className="fa fa-camera"></i>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-4 col-xxl-5col d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
                  <div className="header-dropdown-link">
                    {/* <CompareMenu /> */}
                    <Link
                      to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/shop/wishlist`}
                      className="wishlist-link"
                    >
                      <i className="icon-heart-o"></i>
                      <span className="wishlist-count">
                        {props.wishlist.length}
                      </span>
                      <span className="wishlist-txt">Wishlist</span>
                    </Link>
                    <CartMenu />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Is there some css that goes along with this code?  There are several classNames in your code that I don't believe are standard with bootstrap-4.  It could be the custom css that is hiding your search bar on smaller screen sizes.  Also, it is just the search input that is hiding on smaller screen sizes or the entire row that the search input is in?

Comment: Basically you have got `d-none & d-lg-block` on more than one place which cause to hide element .Try removing `d-none` and `d-lg-block`. And your bootstrap `className` are also wrong in many places fix them all.